# Playstation 3 HDD Change - "Cannot start.The correct hard disk was not found."

Tags: ps3, technical-issues

Error message when it boots is in the topic : "Cannot start.The correct hard disk was not found."

I have a 40GB old PS3 model, and i was swapping the system drive for a 60GB Corsair SSD Force Series.

- Before HDD swap i did backup to another USB HDD i had lying around.
- After HDD swap

  - Insert Corsair from wrapping: This error.
  - Make partition on Corsair format as FAT32. This error.
  - Make sure partition on Corsair is MBR not GUID. This error.
  - Put FW 3.50 on USB stick in PS3\UPDATE. This error.
  - Hold power button until two quick beeps to enter diag menu. This error.

What i haven't tried: Putting in another hdd that's not the original (that's coming now,i have a 120 and 320 lying about to test with).

Anyone had similar issues or tips?

Comment: How did you copy the data to the new drive? If you haven't used some type of cloning tool, then the master boot record hasn't been carried over, rendering the SSD unable to boot. Please note I don't have any PS3 specific knowledge, but I assume PS3 has some kind of BIOS which searches for a boot record to boot from. So what you need to do is clone the drive to another.

Comment: For those who want to do the same process without any problems, just follow the steps indicated in the instruction manual of your PS3 and everything should be done properly.

Comment: @Bora - From old drive you use the backup utility. For new drive, partitions does not have to be of any sort at all it seems. The X25 was not cloned over and detected fine in the PS3.

Comment: @SilverM-A - The problem was "not" not knowing what I was doing, but in fact incompatibility / fault on the Corsair Force Series SSD drives and PS3 (and maybe others)

Comment: Learning something new everyday ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put in an X25MG2 160GB to see that it would detect an SSD. No problem, it asks to format. So i look at the partition table of the X25, and make similar on the Corsair, 100mb (like the reserved for win7 installs), and make another one for rest of drive. Both are formatted as NTFS.

I put it back in the PS3 and it asks to format, which is done in 2 seconds, now it's up and running at the XMB :)

Comment: Another day and the corsair refuses to be detected again (with all stuff on it). I've replaced the corsair with the Intel X25M G2 160GB SSD and had numerous reboots and system restarts, and not a single error (so far).